# Testing custom hook with react-hooks-testing-library throws an error

Tags: jestjs, react-hooks-testing-library

I am trying to test a simple hook that fetches some data using axios. However the test is throwing a TypeError: "Cannot read property 'fetchCompanies' of undefined". Here's my custom hook ([the full repo is here](https://github.com/nareshbhatia/stock-charts/blob/master/src/components/CompanySelect/useCompanyList.ts)):

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Company } from '../../models';
import { CompanyService } from '../../services';

export const useCompanyList = (): {
    loading: boolean;
    error: any;
    companies: Array<Company>;
} => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState();
    const [companies, setCompanies] = useState<Array<Company>>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                setLoading(true);
                const companies = await CompanyService.fetchCompanies();

                // Sort by ticker
                companies.sort((a, b) => {
                    if (a.ticker < b.ticker) return -1;
                    if (a.ticker > b.ticker) return 1;
                    return 0;
                });
                setCompanies(companies);
                setLoading(false);
            } catch (e) {
                setError(e);
            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return { loading, error, companies };
};
```

and here's my test:

```
import { renderHook } from 'react-hooks-testing-library';
import { useCompanyList } from './useCompanyList';

const companiesSorted = [
    {
        ticker: 'AAPL',
        name: 'Apple Inc.'
    },
    ...
];

jest.mock('../../services/CompanyService', () => {
    const companiesUnsorted = [
        {
            ticker: 'MSFT',
            name: 'Microsoft Corporation'
        },
        ...
    ];

    return {
        fetchCompanies: () => companiesUnsorted
    };
});

describe('useCompanyList', () => {
    it('returns a sorted list of companies', () => {
        const { result } = renderHook(() => useCompanyList());

        expect(result.current.loading).toBe(true);
        expect(result.current.error).toBeUndefined();
        expect(result.current.companies).toEqual(companiesSorted);
    });
});
```

Please help me understand how to use react-hooks-testing-library in this case.

**Edit**

This seems to be related to a Jest issue that was seemingly resolved. Please see https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/3209.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The

> TypeError: "Cannot read property 'fetchCompanies' of undefined"

is caused by the way you define the `CompanyService` service. In the code, you are exporting an object `CompanyService` with all the service methods. But in your test, you are mocking the `CompanyService` to return an object with the methods.

So, the mock should return a `CompanyService` object that is an object with all the methods:

```
jest.mock('../../services/CompanyService', () => {
    const companiesUnsorted = [
        {
            ticker: 'MSFT',
            name: 'Microsoft Corporation'
        },
        ...
    ];

    return {
        CompanyService: {
            fetchCompanies: () => companiesUnsorted
        }
    };
});
```

Now, once you solve this, you will find that you don't have the `TypeError` anymore but your test is not passing. That is because the code you are trying to test is asynchronous, but your test is not. So, immediately after you render your hook (through `renderHook`) `result.current.companies` will be an empty array.

You will have to wait for your promise to resolve. Fortunately, `react-hooks-testing-library` provides us a `waitForNextUpdate` function in order to wait for the next hook update. So, the final code for the test would look:

```
it('returns a sorted list of companies', async () => {
    const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() => useCompanyList());

    expect(result.current.loading).toBe(true);
    expect(result.current.error).toBeUndefined();
    expect(result.current.companies).toEqual([]);

    await waitForNextUpdate();

    expect(result.current.loading).toBe(false);
    expect(result.current.error).toBeUndefined();
    expect(result.current.companies).toEqual(companiesSorted);
});
```

Comment: You are the man, @mgarcia! Test is working now. The only glitch is that I am getting the warning "An update to TestHook inside a test was not wrapped in act(...)", but I guess that's a known issue: https://github.com/mpeyper/react-hooks-testing-library/issues/14

Comment: Yes, I did note that... Unfortunately, as you point in your comment, it seems that until the issue is not solved, we will have to live with that warning :(